# Unable to setup semantic-ui-react in a React project

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am trying to setup semantic ui react using the steps given https://react.semantic-ui.com/theming. But i don't know what is going wrong here.

/craco.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [{ plugin: require('@semantic-ui-react/craco-less') }],
}
```

/src/semantic-ui/theme.config

```
....
/*******************************
            Folders
*******************************/

/* Path to theme packages */
@themesFolder : 'themes';
@siteFolder  : '../../src/semantic-ui/site';


@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';

/* Path to site override folder */
@siteFolder  : 'site';

....
```

Error:

```
@import (multiple) "theme.less";
^ Can't resolve in <path>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a 2021 update to `semantic-ui` theming & site styling configuration using create-react-app (CRA) setup (works with `react-scripts` version 4.0.3)

In the project root my `craco.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      plugin: require("@semantic-ui-react/craco-less"),
      options: {
        lessLoaderOptions: {
          lessOptions: {
            math: "always",
            javascriptEnabled: true,
          },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
};
```

This is to allow always math mode for LESS loader. The newer one-line configuration that is presented in the Theming site of react.semantic-ui.com does not work at least with CRA Typescript.

Inside the file `./src/semantic-ui/theme.config`

```
/*******************************
            Folders
*******************************/

/* Path to theme packages */
@themesFolder : 'themes';

/* Path to site override folder */
@siteFolder  : '../../src/semantic-ui/site';

/*******************************
         Import Theme
*******************************/

@import (multiple) "~semantic-ui-less/theme.less";
@fontPath : '../../../themes/@{theme}/assets/fonts';
/* End Config */
```

Your site path is incorrect since inside `themes.config` the siteFolder is relative to a location inside `node_modules` location. Instead, we will change it to point inside the `src/semantic-ui` folder as previously shown.

Please note when testing theme support:

1. Not all elements implement all themes, check beforehand from `node_modules` themes folder which themes can be used (are implemented as code). For example: Segment only allows 'default' or 'github' themes. Please see for example [segment docs at 1.semantic-ui.com](https://1.semantic-ui.com/elements/segment.html).
2. Find documentation on how overriding works, for example, adding `@pageBackground #3450ad` in `semantic-ui/site/globals/site.variables` changes `body` background color as documentation suggests. This is good way of testing whether 'site' configuration works as expected.